# How to get details from link_click_id in Branch.io

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, branch.io

When clicking the button from the email which has the below Branch URL

> http://my.app.link/feed/response/MyUniQuEId

redirect me to my app but the url received is something like below:

> myapp://open?link_click_id=123456789

How can we get the *http://my.app.link/feed/response/MyUniQuEId* from the link click id in react native.

When opening from messenger these links are not getting changed but when clicking from mail the branch URL is getting changed like above.

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

You can not read the referring link from the link click ID. It's a unique parameter that Branch appends for attribution.

Please reference the following documentation to read the deep link data and you can check for the referring link in the link payload given by the Branch SDK - https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native#read-deep-link

Comment: But then how to Deep-link with the specific URL. Because we are sending my.app.link/feed/response/MyUniQuEId but its getting changed. And the app is already installed, then how shall we navigate the user to a specific page? This is happening when clicking from the mail.

Using the read deep link code we are getting the below response.
{"+clicked_branch_link": false, "+is_first_session": false, "+non_branch_link": "backfeed://open?link_click_id=123456789"}

Comment: The query parameters that you are appending to the link would be available in the SDK response.

Comment: same issue faced here. any help would be appreciated in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Make sure to double check that the deep link is configured correctly in the manifest.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="https" android:host="my.app.link" />
</intent-filter>
```